# How to place an foreground image on a java script slider container?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a slider module with javascript and a css template that I need to modify to place an image over the top of the slider to make a rounded frame for the bottom.

```
#slide-outer_[MODULEID] {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000 url('[PATH]/Slider-Foreground.png') no-repeat;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Here is [the page](http://www.sbsclientservices.com/Home.aspx)

You can see the foreground image load in the background of the first slide image, but then it disappears.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Well, I played a bit with your html via the element inspector and I think I got what you need. 
This is a general idea and you might need to adjust and I only experiment that on Chrome.

There's a div element where the loader image/area exists.
I added another div element just below it. see the code and the screenshot (I cannot upload the screenshot stackoverflow doesn't allow it :))

```
    <div id="mss-slider_3701" style="
    background: #FFF url('/DesktopModules/Markit.SlideShow/Templates/JJ-Rasper-Clone 1/Slider-Foreground.png') no-repeat;
">
      <div id="slide-loading_3701" style="display: none;"> </div>

      <!-- !! this element was added -->
      <div style="
    backgrou![enter image description here][1]nd: #FFF url('/DesktopModules/Markit.SlideShow/Templates/JJ-Rasper-Clone 1/Slider-Foreground.png') no-repeat;
    width: 800px;
    height: 184px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000000;
    opacity: .5;
    top: 0px;
"></div>


      <div id="slide-wrapper_3701" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <div id="slide-outer_3701" style="position: absolute; width: 1580px; left: -443.98px;">
          <div class="slide" style="visibility: visible; zoom: 1; opacity: 0.4016846526922899; position: relative; float: left;">
            <div class="slide-inner">
              <img src="/DesktopModules/Markit.SlideShow/ImageHandler.ashx?img=/Portals/50/SlideShow_Photos/3701/Community-Center-S.png&amp;w=840&amp;h=234&amp;Q=0&amp;PortalID=50" alt="Welcome to your Community">
              <div class="mss-introtext_3701">

              <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1;"></div><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 2;"><div style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; height: 0px;"><div class="slidetext_3701" id="slide_201" style="margin: -174px 0px 0px;">
                  <div class="slidetitle">Welcome to your Community</div>
                  <div class="slidesubtitle">Make the Winston Community Center your first step in planning your Wedding, Banquet, Birthday</div>
                  <div class="readonReplacement"> </div>
                </div></div></div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide" style="visibility: visible; zoom: 1; opacity: 0.5983153473077101; position: relative; float: left;">
            <div class="slide-inner">
              <img src="/DesktopModules/Markit.SlideShow/ImageHandler.ashx?img=/Portals/50/SlideShow_Photos/3701/wedding.png&amp;w=840&amp;h=234&amp;Q=0&amp;PortalID=50" alt="Planning a Wedding?">
              <div class="mss-introtext_3701">

              <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1;"></div><div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 2;"><div style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; height: 168px;"><div class="slidetext_3701" id="slide_202" style="margin: 0px;">
                  <div class="slidetitle">Planning a Wedding?</div>
                  <div class="slidesubtitle">Our large Grand Room can accommodate large weddings, and our wedding package is priced for any budget. </div>
                  <div class="readonReplacement"> </div>
                </div></div></div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Arik, that put me on the right path. Here is what I ended up with:     #slide-wrapper_[MODULEID]:after {content: ""; background: url('[PATH]/Slider-Foreground2.png') no-repeat; width: 800px; height: 184px; position: absolute; z-index: 1000000; top: 0px; }